# Why does WordPress download a page instead of opening it?

Tags: php, wordpress, caching

I changed host for one of my site.
Now the Wp blog doesn't work. The home works, but every internal link I click start index.php download instead open the paga and a string is added to URL:

http://www.exemple.com/blog/#.V2B72_mLSCg

I tried to rename plugins directory, but never changed.
I tried to activate xcache_3 in php, but instead to download the page it directly shows the php code.

I tried to repleace .htaccess with the default version, but nothing changed...

This is the actual [.htaccess](http://codepad.org/JYvuEC6B) code

The blog is in a directory like: http://www.exemple.com/blog

Thanks

UPDATE: php is not active, the home is visible because is chached. I tried to switch php versione but it was the same.

UPDATE 2: There was a htaccess outside public_html, the assistance removed it

Comment: If you empty the .htaccess file, does the issue still happen? If so then sounds like the issue is with your server configuration, if not then there'll be a line there that's causing this issue and you can remove section by section to narrow it down.

Comment: @JamieBicknell Nothing changes. Problably It's really a server configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same issue when I moved my site.  The solution for me was to change hosting PHP support from Apache to FastCGI.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a line in the .htaccess file:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70s .php
```

Just commented that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the version of **PHP** in my case I update it from **5.6** to **7.4**

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by installing PHP on my server :

```
sudo apt-get install -y php8.1-cli php8.1-common php8.1-mysql php8.1-zip php8.1-gd php8.1-mbstring php8.1-curl php8.1-xml php8.1-bcmath
```

Answer (score -1):

I just resolved the issue by deleting **.htaccess** file and saving permalinks setting.